# cannot setText to a textview in android studio app

Tags: android, string, locale, settext

Im having problem in passing the language locale to a string.
Code is very simple, and i can display the language whit a toast, but i cannot set inside a text.
In this moment, `language` returns: "it", "fr", "en".

`//helperLang.setText("Italian");` is commented because app get crash.

My code:

```
public void loadLocale(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = preferences.getString("My_Lang","");

    helperLang = findViewById(R.id.helperText_lang);

   

    if(language.equals("it")){
        //helperLang.setText("Italian");
        Toast.makeText(this, "italian", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(language.equals("fr")){
       // helperLang.setText("French");
        Toast.makeText(this, "French", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
       // helperLang.setText("English");
        Toast.makeText(this, "English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add crash log

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

I was declaring `helperLang.setText("Italian")` inside the method, but actually, it goes outside on global scope. Then i modified my method as follow:

```
    helperLang = findViewById(R.id.helperText_lang);
    helperLang.setText(loadLocale());



public String loadLocale(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = preferences.getString("My_Lang", "");

    if(language.equals("it")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "italian", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "Italian";
    }else if(language.equals("fr")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "French", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "French";
    }else{
       return "English";
    }

}
```